# Access controller from other controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I started with cakephp yesterday and ran in a Problem:

I've got an "ImagesController" and an "UsersController".

The ImageView displays a list of images. The user is saved in the images table with the userid.

I now need to convert the userid to a name that is in the users table. I tried it with helpers but it didn't work as I can't access `$this->User->find($id)`.

I already searched on google, but seems im naming it wrong so it doesn't get results.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is associating your Image model to your User model. The [article in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) is really worth a read!

Once they are associated, you can just get the name directly without calling any functions. From the top of my head, what you'd need is to add this in your Image model:

```
public $belongsTo = array('User');
```

Then from your view the username should be available under:

```
$data_var['Image']['User']['name'];
```

Where `$data_var` is the View variable that holds your image data.

Comment: $belongsTo is the point! Thanks! But it isn't accepting my conditions I made:

    `public function index() {
        $conditions = array(
            'recursive' => -1,
            'order' => array('id DESC'),
            'limit' => 15,
            'page' => 1,
        );
pr($this->Image->find('all', $conditions));`

Comment: That's because your conditions array is flawed. `recursive` doesn't go in there. Try comparing it with the first example [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) to see what it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two models, `Image` and `User`. If you want to be able to call `$this->User->find($id)`, you can add the model into the `$uses` variable at the top of your cotroller.

```
var $uses = array('Image','User');
```

for example.

Comment: Hey, yay, nearly what I wanted! How can I call functions from it? Like `$this->User->getUserNameById(1);`

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That's exactly how you call it. Alternatively, you can set up model associations, so calling `$this->Image->find()` will also pull in `User` data. Here's the documentation on that. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: Hey, seems it's not the way I'd like to have it:

`<?php
class Image extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Image';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className'  => 'User',
            'conditions'   => array('User.verified' => '1')
        )
    );
}`

Just returns me the old Image->find() output.

Comment: Actually, this is not a good answer, Oldskool's answer is correct. I can't find the link with reasons *why* this is not good, but I remember reading about it. I think it just creates overhead or something like that. If you have a proper association, you can access the other model with `$this->Image->User->find(...)`. If you don't have an association, then it *may* be correct, if the model is used in all actions.